# Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined mixin 'transition'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting error

> Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined mixin 'transition'
>    while doing assets pre-compile.

I have following things in my code:

**application.css.scss**

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

**custom.css.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";

@import "font-awesome";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
```

Please let me know in case I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: You don't need to manually precompile your code in development mode. Your styles will be auto-compiled for each HTTP response. Could you post the full error?  Also, are you referencing "transition" in your code?

Comment: Can I have some files with .css and some with .css.scss in assets folder ? Do you have any idea ? I am facing issues for pre-compiling these.

Comment: yeah, you put them in app/assets/stylesheets and then require them using `*= require` in application.css